# Packaging google canary in SCCM

Tags: google-chrome, sccm, chrome-canary

for our system software center in SCCM we'd like to offer google canary and make them required software for some deployments. Has someone succesfully succeeded in doing so?

We have the chromestup.exe currently as our install file and deployed the packet in our store but when we click install the install says it's done but canary isn't installed.

We use the registery BLBeacon/state = 1 as detection method. Which is filled in if you install canary manually.

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

Please can you show me the command you are using to install the product? Have you tested this outside of SCCM to confirm it works? As far as I'm aware, Google Chrome Canary does not support unattended installations by default.

Comment: Hi, I do not use a command to install it, though i know that ChromeSetup.exe /silent /install works i would already be happy that it installs even with a pop-up or 2. if i use the chromsetup.exe /silent /install it works though and is installed but if it installs thorugh system center it does not work ( with or without the commands)

Comment: If you've confirmed that the command works outside of SCCM that would suggest the issue is with how you've set up the Application/Package. What happens when the software is deployed? A good place to start would be checking the CCM logs. Have a read here if you need some guidance on this: https://www.swc.com/blog/microsoft-system-center/sccm-troubleshooting-101-log-files

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and used the Google Beta found on the Enterprise page - it should basically be the same version but packaged as an MSI making it easy for SCCM delivery.